# can we safely upgrade a cassandra cluster with more memory and cpu?

Tags: cassandra

All of our cassandra nodes will be VMs. If we load data and begin using the system, can we easily add more cpus and memory to the VM at a later date? Will Cassandra automatically handle that? Is there changes we would need to make?

This would be with version 2.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your virtualization layer allows you to add CPUs and memory, there should be no problem.

You may need to adjust the Java heap settings (See `conf/cassandra-env.sh`) to allocate more memory to Cassandra, which will require a rolling restart of each affected node (depending on your virtualization layer, you may need a restart anyway to add CPU/RAM, and Java probably requires a restart to detect additional CPUs).

Note that you will get best performance (and fault-tolerance) out of Cassandra by running on bare metal, not VMs.

You may also want to consider upgrading your cluster by adding more nodes, rather than increasing the resources of each existing node - but this depends on your use case.

See also:

- [Tuning Java resources](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html) (Datastax)

Comment: But can't you accommodate for the performance of VMs but having more nodes in the cluster?  And I suspect we could eventually migrate to bare metal and phase out the VMs if we needed to?

Comment: Yes, agreed on both counts. VMs are also very useful for experimentation and test.